# Start Activity From Wallpaper Service (not preference related...)

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I have a live Wallpaper. This live wallpaper has a settings page implemented from PreferenceActivity. Everything works as expected. So far, so good.

From my Wallpaper Settings page..I want to start another activity (a details activity...with info, bitmaps, links, etc...). When I start this activity I get a security exception error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {... } from ProcessRecord ... requires android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER
```

The manifest has the required permission. I've tried putting this permission everywhere .. even in multiple locations (not just in the service tag in the manifest).  I'm starting the Activity from the wallpaper settings page with a new intent, then calling startActivity.

Does anyone know why I'm getting the permission denial even when the permission is included? Can someone tell me how to start the activity correctly without getting a force close?

Much appreciated.

Comment: add `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"` to your service inside manifest and remove this permission from every where in manifest

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the answer and it worked. I greatly appreciate the help!